# Unable to apply font family from css in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am facing weird problem that I have an HTML page where I have a BUTTON on which I want to apply css font-family. I wrote it & applied to button. However, it is not applying that font-family to the button. It looks like default button.

Below is my code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";

}

.button-2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(224, 46%, 61%);
    border: medium none;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 10px;
font-family: "Open Sans";
    margin-top:-18px;
}
.button-2:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(224, 38%, 42%);
}

.button-1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(224, 46%, 61%);
    border: medium none;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button-1:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(224, 38%, 42%);
}

.SixBlockerHeading  {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(224, 46%, 61%);
    border: medium none;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 20px;
}
.SixBlockerHeading span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(224, 38%, 42%);
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.SixBlockerHeading {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(224, 46%, 61%);
    border: medium none;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    display: inline;
    float: left;
   font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 37px;
    margin-top: 21px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 354px;
}

.NewStyle
{
   text-transform:none;
   float: float;
   color: hsl(224, 38%, 42%);
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   font-size: 15px;
   margin-top: -10px; 
font-family: "Open Sans";
   margin-left:180px;
   display: inline;
}

-->
</style>



<a href="url goes here"><input type="submit" class="button-1" value="ADD"></a>
<a  href="url goes here"><input type="submit" class="button-2"  style=" background: hsl(224, 38%, 42%);" value="DONE"></a>


<h1 class="NewStyle" ><Strong>NEW PAGE</Strong></h1>
<div>
```

Comment: Be careful to declare your `font-family` only one time, here it's declared two times in your `button-2`. Otherwise, you should have a look on the **font stacks** (http://www.cssfontstack.com/) to have a *default font* as a *fallback* in case your main font wouldn't be compatible. I.E here: `font-family: "Open Sans", Calibri, sans-serif;`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be missing the font itself. You can include it inside the CSS with:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

It is also possible with HTML only:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

... or JavaScript (not recommended):

```
WebFontConfig = {
    google: {
        families: [ 'Open+Sans::latin' ]
    }
};

(function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try

Comment: As @atmd said, you should use `sans-serif` as a fallback for users who can't display this font for any reason

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the `font-family: "Open Sans";` font 
(it's not installed by default)

You can either include it locally (store the font on your server) with `@font-face`. There is a good generator [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Alternatively you can use something like google webfonts and add this to your html: (inside the `head` tags)

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

They use it with: `font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;`

(Providing the sans-serif font as a fall back)

You can find the full list of open sans font weights/styles [here](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try